# Unpacking bz2 with tar

Tags: tar, bzip2

Extremely new to the command line (read: no clue what I'm doing), so I have been trying to teach myself some basic commands by doing some run of the mill stuff. Currently trying to install Marathon on my computer by following the instructions on: https://github.com/Aleph-One-Marathon/alephone/wiki/Linux%20Install%20Instructions

I am trying to run,

```
tar xjvf AlephOne-20150619.tar.bz2
```

But I get the error,

```
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2.
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now.
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on or offer some suggestions as to what I should do? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read the error: "bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file." so either it is not a bzip2 file or it is corrupt. run `file AlephOne-20150619.tar.bz2` and post the output

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, well, now I feel silly. It was an HTML document. I specified the URL wrong in my cURL command. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tar: Child returned status 2

Simple : You got a corrupt package. Please delete, and download a new one: http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/marathon/Aleph%20One/2015-06-19/AlephOne-20150619.tar.bz2

---

About tar :

> From /usr/doc/tar-1.15.1/NEWS , slackware 10.2 , tar version 1.15 -
>   Sergey Poznyakoff, **2004**-12-20
>
> - Compressed archives are recognised automatically, it is no longer necessary to specify -Z, -z, or -j options to read them.  ( Thus, you
>     can now run `tar tf archive.tar.gz'.)

So with an OS from year 2005 or later you can just do:
`tar xvf [archive]` with tar.gz and tar.bz2.
And around 2009, suffix .xz was also added, for lzma compressed archives.

Answer (score 0):

try (no ***j*** option). **-j** is for filter the archive through bzip2

```
tar -xvf AlephOne-20150619.tar.bz2
```

to know file format:

```
file AlephOne-20150619.tar.bz2
```

source: [tar manual](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-tar/#lbAH)

Comment: Please do not post guesses as answers, [edit] your answer with some evidence why this should work.